# how to crawl public profiles of a user on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to crawl the public information of a user on facebook. The user and I are not friend. But in my facebook account, I can see the public profile and also feeds of the user. I can get the user's id, for example, 12345678. Then I use the graph api: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/12345678?fields=feed`. However, I cannot get any feed information. Could you give me some help on how to crawl public profiles of a user ?

Comment: You can not get feed without having the user grant read_stream permission

Comment: user profiles who did not authorize your app are none of your business ;)

Comment: but why can I see it ? I think if I can see it, then I can crawl it. Am I right ?